# Is there a way for hxcpp to cross compile with Java?

Tags: java, haxeflixel, hxcpp

I am asking this question because I keep getting an error with NativeCFFI in a haxeflixel project (it's not my project) when I try to build Java with haxeflixel's lime, and I am wondering what I should do to make hxcpp cross compile with Java? A command I need to run, or code that should be imported? I want to know how I can do this. I apparently tried to exclude NativeCFFI but then found out later it was needed.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Found this: https://gist.github.com/darmie/99fbd3512b49d0b8cc11fb93bf2b3f8c. Not sure if it works.

I'm not sure how to do this (Maybe you can make a GitHub issue on HaxeFlixel's page), but you could possibly use REST APIs as a way to use Java code within HaxeFlixel -- https://api.haxeflixel.com/lime/net/HTTPRequest.html -- expose your Java app over a REST API and consume it using `lime.net.HTTPRequest`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)